# how do i assign dynamic array values in a single variable in php?

Tags: php

```
   <?php  
       $result="";  
       for($j=1;$j<=$lettt;$j++)
          {
            for($i=1;$i<=$lettt;$i++)
             {
                $sel3=$_POST["letter2".$i];
                $sel4=$sel3-1;
                if($i===$j)
                {
                   echo $finalL[$j][$sel4];
                   $result=$result+$finalL[$j][$sel4];
                }   
              }
            }
      echo $result;
        ?>
```

Here echo $finalL[$j][$sel4]; is working correctly and giving desired result. I am trying to store the $finalL[$j][$sel4] values in a single variable, say $result, so i can use it anywhere else without using for loop again and again. I am not getting my desired result (getting 0 everytime), i am a newbie and here to learn more. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

solution was simple lol, just changing

`$result=$result+$finalL[$j][$sel4];`

to
`$result=$result.$finalL[$j][$sel4];`
solved the problem.